# Problems seeting up a simple countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong? I am new to jquery and I would like to have some feedback. Basically what I want is some sort of a countdown timer that would display how many days are left till an event happens. The event is a set date.

thank you for your help

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Almost Vacation</title>

 <script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
   $('document').on('ready', calc);
    function calc(){
        var myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setMonth(05, 06);
        var today = new Date();
        today.getDay();
        var x = myDate - today;
        $('#aantal p').text(x);
}



 </script>       

 <style type="text/css">
   p {
      color:red; 
      font-size:1.8em; 
      margin:-90px 10px 5px;
   }

 </style>

 </head>

 <body>

        <img src="http://fed.cmd.hro.nl/upload/files/1011/y1/q4/w3/slapende_student.jpg" width="462" height="275" />

    <p>Vacation starts in<span id="aantal">&nbsp;</span> Days</p>
 </body>


 </html>
```

Comment: Tip: write small pieces of code and test them.

Comment: @undefined. Though he should have mentioned, read my answer.

Comment: @gdoron okay man, +1, that's correct. solved one of the problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be:

```
$(function() {
    var myDate = new Date();
    myDate.setMonth(06, 06); //set date forward in time, not backward
    var today = new Date();
    var x = (myDate - today)/86400000;
    $('#aantal').text(x); //append to the span, not the p that does not exists
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Da8h6/2/)

Comment: `getDay` returns the day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('document').on('ready', calc);
```

Should be:

```
$(document).ready(calc);
```

Or simply:

```
$(calc);
```

`$('document')` is looking for elements of the type `<document>`
while `$(document)` wraps the `document` node with a jQuery object.

Comment: thank you gdoron, I did what you told me to do, but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the syntax correction that gdoron pointed out, you are getting the range incorrectly. First, you want to subtract `myDate` from `today` instead of the other way around. Also, the result of this subtraction is the number of milliseconds between the dates, so you need to do a little unit converting to get to days. Finally, you jQuery selector was incorrect.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(calc);
    function calc(){
        var myDate = new Date();
        myDate.setMonth(5, 6);
        var today = new Date();
        var x = (today - myDate)/(1000*60*60*24);
        $('#aantal').text(x); // update this selector too!!
    }
</script>
```

If you decide that you want to round this number you can do something like:

```
var x = Math.ceil((today - myDate)/(1000*60*60*24));
```

Comment: @MasterIvinChickenSheep glad it works! mark the answer as accepted by checking the checkbox next to the one you used.